# What classes to use for high-frequency readings from a sensor (e.g. accelerometer) in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-sensors

I am working on an app to monitor the accelerometer and write to a file, at a frequency high enough to be able to detect bumps in a road (~100Hz). I would like to be able to start and stop the recording from a button in the main UI.

My initial approach was using a Service (implementing the SensorEventListener class, with a BufferedWriter to write the events to a file). My problem with this approach was that at a listening frequency high enough for my detection purposes, the UI freezes, and the user never even gets to press "stop the service".
An IntentService will not work since there is no "task to complete", just a continuous listening. I successfully wrapped the Service in an AsyncTask, which seems to work just fine, however this class is not suggested for ongoing tasks (and this will have to be on for the duration of a car ride, ~30min).

I don't know much about Android yet -- what structure would be recommended in this case? Why should I not use an AsyncTask?

Comment: You may be better off storing all of your data dynamically in your application until the sensor has been turned off or something and then dump of your data into a file. It seems like it might be difficult to have you app perform 100 file writes/second. Not sure though, haven't worked at that frequency before.

Comment: Thanks for that idea, I think there might be too much data for dynamic storage though... I used the AsyncTask, which seems to be working, and fingers crossed nothing goes wrong; I'd still like to know if there's a "proper way" to do this.

Comment: Since you need a long living thread, why not use default java Thread? If there's no need to access UI thread from background thread I don't see much use for AsyncTask.